# All sub-arrays with sum less than X and greater than Y

Tags: python, arrays

```py
def find_subarr(arr: tuple, value):
    arr = tuple(arr)
    if sum(arr) <= value:
        return set()

    ret = { arr }
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        tmp_arr = list(arr)
        del tmp_arr[i]
        tmp_arr = tuple(tmp_arr)
        ret |= find_subarr(tmp_arr, value)

    return ret

subarrays = find_subarr([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5], 0.4)
for subarr in sorted(subarrays, key=lambda l: (len(l), sum(l))):
    print(subarr)
```

This returns all sub-arrays with sum greater than 0.4

I want to add one more condition that sum should be less than 0.7

Tried changing Line 3 with `if (sum(arr) <= value or sum(arr) >= 0.7)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Think about it, if your array is `(0.5, 0.5)`, then it sums to more than 0.7. However, are there any subarrays that might sum to more than 0.4 and less than 0.7? Your logic needs to account for that.

Comment: @Dunes I added another function which checks other condition. Its working as expected. Result was: `(0.1, 0.4)`,`(0.2, 0.3)`,`(0.1, 0.5)`,`(0.2, 0.4)`,`(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)`,`(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)`,`(0.1, 0.2, 0.4)` Would appreciate any feedback or suggestions to improve this code: https://pastebin.com/k6h4tkbe

Comment: Please edit your question, rather than providing a pastebin link. But from a quick glance, it seems you aren't producing 1-length tuples like `(0.5,)`.